# how to mail the output of the shell script on your mail ID

Tags: operating-system

I have created the shell script and that script is giving me the output, the script checks whether daily backup is completed or not. now I want a mail about the status of the backup on my mail ID and whether the backup is completed or not.

I am using Centos 7 VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl: https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/smtp.

Or some cli mail clients like ssmtp: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSMTP